# On Visual Studio Code: How to run commands with no keybiding?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to using Visual Studio Code

I'm trying to configure it so that it behaves as much as possible to the old editor that I wanted to use. While configuring keybinding I found several commands that I'm interested in trying out:

[image]

My question is is simple, is there anyway to try out commands with no key binding, to see what they do? (forexample Reindent Lines or Reindent Selected Lines in the picture above)

Comment: Most/All commands are also available in the **View** > **Command Palette**

Comment: Yes. I figured out that I opented the command pallete, search for the command, and then click on the selection, the command is triggered. But the first time, I tried to do this it failed and I don't know why. Anyways I'm much happier with Visual Code Studio now